# 'Unrecognized selector' error when adding GestureRecognizer to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I've seen numerous posts surrounding this exact issue, but nothing has helped. I'm trying to programmatically add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIView that I am instantiating and adding at runtime. The recognizer appears to be getting added correctly, but I get the following error whenever I perform a tap

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101e400f0

Here's my code (Using Swift 3):

```
    let mask = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.width!, height: self.height!))
    let tappy = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    mask.addGestureRecognizer(tappy)
    self.addSubview(mask)
```

And the method I'm trying to call with each tap:

```
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer!) {
         // handling code
         print("Tap")
    }
```

Thanks much for your help

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that Xcode gives me the following warning at the line where the Recognizer is being instantiated:

> No method declared with Objective-C selector 'handleTap:'

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. It's not appropriate to edit your question to include the answer. The answer is in the duplicate.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks much